# System halts while copying a large file

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, filesystem

I am trying to copy a large file of size (approx. 40 GB) but most of the times system halts while copying the file (after 50%). Sometimes it copies the file as well.  I have tried to change the Operating system. I used Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 but the issue persists. Some observations are listed below.

- System halts more likely while copying from GUI than terminal
- System halts more likely while copying using cp than rsync

My System specs are:

- Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8
- 16 GB RAM and 1 Terabyte Hard disk

What can be the cause of this issue and how can I diagnose it exactly?

Attached below is the image showing my filesystem in GParted.
[image: Gparted View of Filesystem]

Comment: Where are you copying the file to? An external drive or something?

Comment: Copying from external drive to system hard drive

Comment: And is it a single ~40GB file?

Comment: Yes it is 40 GB file. This issue isn't consistent. It occurs most of the times but not always. :/

Comment: You are copying to your system hard drive. To what directory are you copying? To /home/<user> probably.... Is that directory a child of the /  directory?  If so, you unwillingly might be filling up the / to a point that Ubuntu cannot create temporary system files and it will crash. Solution: create a partition with adequate size and mount it as /home during boot (/etc/fstab). If you need help with this, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Willem. Yes I was copying to /home/${USERNAME}/${DIR}/ And yes it is child directory of / directory, since every /home/{USERNAME}/ directory is child of / . 
I didn't understand the logic of temporary system files creation, please tell me more details. I want to know how it works?
Secondly if the cause is as you specified, why it works sometimes?

Comment: Sorry for the wait. Please use @WillemK at the start of a comment, so I don't miss it. The logic of temp files. Well, the easiest example is /tmp. You see files owned by root and they are created/maintained/erased daily. Then there is the .cache directory in your own home directory, which is used by many application, for example your web browser.

Comment: Why it works sometimes: applications (and Ubuntu kernel too) often have settings to perform auto-clean. F.e. my Firefox limits at 350MB. I think when your 40GB is removed, your disk shows about that amount of free space. On a good day auto-clean has recently run and your file upload goes flawless. On a bad day... well, you guessed it...
Solution: depend on the size of your internal disk. Would be nice if you had enough unallocated space left to create a partition and mount it as /home. It will need a special procedure but it is not difficult.

Comment: @WillemK Thanks for explanation but why /tmp is used while copying from external hard drive to my system. It works like simple copy and past. Data is copied from one location ( my external hard drive ) to my system ( lets say /home/user/targetfolder/ )

Comment: I did not say your process is using /tmp. Your copy action indeed does not, it uses cache (RAM). I said /tmp is one of the temporary storage places that Ubuntu uses in the background. It will be difficult to determine which system processes are involved and who should you want to? Your big 40G file is the problem. Your file system is not correctly configured for accommodating such large files. You will have to reconfigure the file system if you want to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @WillemK. Now I get it! If i tell you my filesystem configuration and details. Can you help me in pinpointing the cause and fixing it?

Comment: I can help you but there is a time constraint. I am flying to Thailand on the 11th, so I will be off-line for a day or 2.  But we can see how far we get. Or are you able to cut your 40GB file in half and process it in 2 times? Meanwhile paste a screen print of your disk layout in gparted into your question above..

Comment: @WillemK Sure buddy, take your time. I have added the image link in the question. Please respond when you are free.

Comment: What I mentioned about temporary files is still valid, but having seen the layout of your disk, 500+ GB free, it suggests you can copy your file without any space problems. So we need to look further. Your external drive is connected via USB or SATA? I have been look around and found other posts with USB timeouts with large files. So what does your 40GB consist of? How is it created? Are you getting it from an external source? If possible, I would try to copy it on a per-file basis. Another option would be using the `dd` program so you can determine an optimal block size.

Comment: @WillemK External hard drive is connected via USB. 40GB consist of a single file with dlt extension. If it is USB issue then it should occur always. Am I right?

Comment: I have experienced irregular behaviour when I copied a large file (20GB tar) from my USB.As cp doesn't show any progress info, I installed 'pv' and entered the following command:  cd /media/'user'/'usbmountpnt' ; cat file | pv | dd of=/home/'user'/file. Now I get an indicator of the throughput. On average it showed around 30MiB/s but for unknown reason I also saw 19KiB/sec. Very odd and I can't explain it.

Comment: Forgot to add I had 1 timeout during three times using the 'cp' command. Using the second command, also 3 times, it always completed successfully but with very different run times; minutes apart. It never halted the system though, with the timeout, just the copy command crashed.